# Will BroadcastReceiver expend battery?

Tags: android

I know the AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver will stay system to keep watch over SMS after I installed the .apk

Will the AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver expend battery even if I never receive s SMS?

Do I need disable the AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver when I stop watch SMS ?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.enabledisablebroadcastreceiver"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.code4reference.enabledisablebroadcastreceiver.EnableDisableBroadcastReceiver"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_enable_disable_boradcast_receiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Broadcast receiver -->
        <receiver android:name="com.code4reference.enabledisablebroadcastreceiver.AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.code4reference.enabledisablebroadcastreceiver.MyInternetServer"></service>

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

</manifest>





import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;

public class AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null && ACTION.compareToIgnoreCase(intent.getAction()) == 0) {
            Object[] pduArray = (Object[]) intent.getExtras().get("pdus");
            SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pduArray.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < pduArray.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pduArray[i]);
                //Log.d("CWCGR1", 
                //      "From: " + messages[i].getOriginatingAddress()+
                //      " Msg: " + messages[i].getMessageBody());
                HandleMsg(context,messages[i].getOriginatingAddress(), messages[i].getMessageBody());
            }
        }       

    }

    private void HandleMsg(Context context,String address, String body ){
        Intent msgIntent = new Intent(context,MyInternetServer.class);        
        msgIntent.putExtra("address", address);
        msgIntent.putExtra("body", body);
        context.startService(msgIntent);
    }
}






import com.example.enabledisablebroadcastreceiver.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class EnableDisableBroadcastReceiver extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnExit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnExit);
        btnExit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }           
        }); 

    }

   public void enableBroadcastReceiver(View view){
       ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(this, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
       PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

       pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
               PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
               PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
       Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled broadcast receiver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

   public void disableBroadcastReceiver(View view){
       ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(this, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
       PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

       pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
               PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
               PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
       Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled broadcst receiver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }   

}
```

Answer (score 8):

As discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/UyQXpI6Jwz0), an incoming SMS belongs to a special group of low-level system events that will cause the CPU to wake from the battery-saving "sleep mode" (this group includes incoming calls, incoming mobile data packets and `AlarmManager` events). The device's GSM radio will listen to incoming SMS regardless of your broadcast receiver being set or not. When an SMS arrives, the system will choose which receiver(s) will handle it. Thus, having a SMS broadcast receiver registered has no impact in the battery consumption. Besides, energy consumption due to a registered receiver in memory is [not significant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906083/correlation-between-memory-usage-of-processes-and-battery-consumption-android).

You can unregister the broadcast receiver programmatically if there is a functional requirement to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have fined your AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver in the android manifest, android will wake up your app and call the AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver every time an sms is received.
If no SMS are received, your app won't be woken up so there won't be any impact on battery.

If you want control over when to receive those broadcasts, register and unregister your receiver programmatically through the registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter) method on a Context (e.g. Activity).